# Thrift server with Hudi (dbt)

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr, dbt, apache-hudi

I'm trying to set up Spark as engine in DBT.

At first I was trying with Thriftserver in EMR 6.11, as per the [docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/core/connect-data-platform/spark-setup), but it's failing with the message stating it can't find the Hudi package

```
20:59:12      Failed to find data source: hudi. Please find packages at
20:59:12      https://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
```

I believe I had to force the packages in the server, so I tried

```
sudo /usr/lib/spark/sbin/start-thriftserver.sh --packages org.apache.hudi:hudi-spark3.3-bundle_2.12:0.13.1  --conf 'spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer' --conf 'spark.sql.extensions=org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.HoodieSparkSessionExtension'
```

But failed again with the same message. Running the sample repo [here](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-spark/blob/main/docker/spark-defaults.conf) works just fine.

I then read about [Kyuubi](https://kyuubi.readthedocs.io/en/master/quick_start/quick_start.html#start-kyuubi) as a Thrift replacement but I end up stumbling upon the same error, even though I set the jars location in the spark-defaults.conf, as suggested [here](https://kyuubi.readthedocs.io/en/master/connector/spark/hudi.html)

This [issue](https://github.com/apache/hudi/issues/9919) states to be an issue with the 0.13.1 version, but even using the 0.12.X shows the same behaviour.

Any ideas ?